# PMD rule for java to avoid using @Autowired annotation on class fields- to not use field injection

Tags: java, spring, pmd

I want to have a pmd rule for my java project which will disallow field injections in Spring(want to use injection by constructor instead). is there any pmd rule for it, or can I create some to have it in my code analysis?

To not allow this:

```
@Autorired
private Object object;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an XPath rule with the following expression:

```
//Annotation
  [pmd-java:typeIs('org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired')]
  [../FieldDeclaration]
```

To add this to your ruleset XML, [see here](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_extending_your_first_rule.html#exporting-to-xml):

```
<rule name="todo"
      language="java"
      message="todo."
      class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule" >
    <description>
TODO
    </description>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
        <property name="xpath">
            <value>
<![CDATA[
//Annotation
  [pmd-java:typeIs('org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired')]
  [../FieldDeclaration]
]]>
            </value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</rule>
```